# Recipients of my gmail don't see my address

Tags: gmail

I receive my gmail on my pc as well as my iphone 4S. When I answer mail via my iphone, the recipient doesn't see my email address, they only see 'Gmail'. Why is this and how can I change it?

Comment: What exactly do they see and what does the raw text show, if they hover over the address what do they see and what do you see in your sent mail?

Answer (score 2):

They are almost certainly seeing the name you entered for yourself in settings. To fix this:

1. Open System Preferences app.
2. Tap on `Mail, Contacts, Calendars`.
3. Tap on the account you are having the problem with.
4. Tap where it says "Account" followed by your email address and a right-facing arrow.
5. In the first box, "Name", it probably says Gmail. Change it to what you want to appear in your return emails.